# Need help in replicating the given design, that is responsive on all large devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to replicate the following design provided by our UI/IX designer.

[image]

I am having a hard time positioning the circular part of the image at the center. (The vertical line and the circular part are two different images)

I tried using the padding-top on the "even part of the divs" and after few hit and trials, I replicated the design on "my device".

```
<!-- Sorry for bad naming conventions. Also, Bootstrap V5.3.0-aplha1 is being Used-->
    <style>
      .cols:nth-of-type(even) {
        padding-top: 17rem;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container text-center">
          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </body>
```

But the problem here is that, the value given on the padding-top works only on "my device". If I view the work on "other device" then the positioning will be all wrong.

Design on My Device:

[image]

Design on Other Device:

[image]

What other methods can I use to replicate the given design responsively on all large devices (Width more than 991px)?. You can skip worrying about devices for width less than 991px. I already have other plans for that.

P.S: [Codesandbox link of my demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mclaren-3lg55v?file=/index.html)

Comment: Can u upload your code to codesandbox, then we can check it on condesandbox!?

Comment: @QuyenNguyen I have added the link of my codesandbox at the end.

Comment: well, I checked it, and you can try my way, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>CDR Services</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Sorry for bad naming conventions.-->
    <!-- <style>
      .cols:nth-of-type(even) {
        padding-top: 18rem;
      }
    </style> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="cdr-services">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cols">
                <div class="col"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- ---------------------------------------- -->

          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="row row-cols-1 g-0">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- ---------------------------------------- -->

          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col">
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col">
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cols">
              <div class="col">
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. This worked for my device as well as my co-workers device as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this. this is much more optimized.. i removed unnecessary codes.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>CDR Services</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="cdr-services">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col"></div>
                <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ---------------------------------------- -->
          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/circle-service.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ---------------------------------------- -->
          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-6">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="cols">
              <img src="./img/line-service.svg" alt="" />
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3>CDR Report Writing</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```